# ¿Cómo puede hacer la impresión de esta forma?

Tags: c#

Sobre las notas de un grupo de alumnos, para sacar promedio de cada uno de los estudiantes, y del grupo de alumnos en general pero me piden que la impresión debe de ser de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya lo intente hacer de varias formas y siempre me sale de forma lineal, ¿alguna sugerencia de cómo podría hacerlo?

Adjunto mi código

Pd: He investigado un poco y creo que se puede hacer con string.format pero no se como implementarlo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace Desafio_practico_oficial
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Alumnos
        {
          public  Double practica1;
           public Double practica2;
           public Double practica3;
        }

        static void Estudiantes()
        {
            Alumnos Acceso = new Alumnos();
            string dato;
            bool valido;

            Double sumaNotas = 0, promedio_general = 0;
            int n_alumnos;
            Double[] promedio_alumno = new Double[100];

            Console.WriteLine("Digite el numero de alumnos: ");
            dato = Console.ReadLine();
            valido = int.TryParse(dato, out n_alumnos);
            if (valido == true)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < n_alumnos; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Alumno: " + (i + 1));
                    Console.WriteLine("Notas de las practicas:");
                    Console.WriteLine("Practica 1: ");
                    Acceso.practica1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Practica 2: ");
                    Acceso.practica2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Practica 3: ");
                    Acceso.practica3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    //Sacando el promedio del alumno
                    promedio_alumno[i] = Acceso.practica1 * 0.25 + Acceso.practica2 * 0.35 + Acceso.practica3 * 0.40;
                    //sacando el promedio general del grupo
                    sumaNotas += promedio_alumno[i];

                    Console.WriteLine("Promedio del alumno: {0}", promedio_alumno[i]);
                   

                    Console.WriteLine("\n");

                }
                promedio_general = (sumaNotas / n_alumnos);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nNOTA PROMEDIO DEL GRUPO: {0} ", promedio_general);

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nNOTA MAXIMA DEL GRUPO: " + promedio_alumno.Max());


                Console.WriteLine("\n\nNOTA MINIMA DEL GRUPO: " + promedio_alumno.Min());
                Console.ReadKey();


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Digite un dato valido");
            }

        }


        static void Mostrar(string[] args)
        {
            Estudiantes();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aquí una ayuda.. primero que nada necesitas guardar tus valores que capturas en un arreglo.

```
         ---->  String[] valorescapturados=null;
                for (int i = 0; i < n_alumnos; i++)
                {
                    valorescapturados= new String[n_alumnos];
                    Console.WriteLine("Alumno: " + (i + 1));
                    Console.WriteLine("Notas de las practicas:");
                    Console.Write("Practica 1: ");
                    Acceso.practica1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Practica 2: ");
                    Acceso.practica2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Practica 3: ");
                    Acceso.practica3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                --->valorescapturados[i] = Acceso.practica1.ToString() + "\t" + Acceso.practica2.ToString() + "\t" + Acceso.practica3.ToString();

                    //Sacando el promedio del alumno
                    promedio_alumno[i] = Acceso.practica1 * 0.25 + Acceso.practica2 * 0.35 + Acceso.practica3 * 0.40;
                    //sacando el promedio general del grupo
                    sumaNotas += promedio_alumno[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Promedio del alumno: {0}", promedio_alumno[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");

                }
```

Despues imprimirlos para esto utiliza `\t` para realizar un tab entre caracteres

```
                Console.WriteLine("No \t Practica1 \t Practica2 \t Practica3");
                int index = 0;
                foreach (String valor in valorescapturados)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} \t {1} \t\t {2} \t\t {3}", index + 1, promedio_alumno[index], promedio_alumno[index + 1], promedio_alumno[index + 2]);

                }
```

Comment: Al momento de de imprimir la nota de cada alumno en las practicas me sale el promedio :(

Comment: a si es que puse el promedio cambia la variable por valores capturados "valorescapturados"

Comment: Me salta la excepcion System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.'

Comment: ¿como lo estas añadiendo?

Comment: 'Console.WriteLine("No \t Practica1 \t Practica2 \t Practica3");
                int index = 0;
                foreach (String valor in valorescapturados)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} \t {1} \t\t {2} \t\t {3}", index + 1, valorescapturados[index],valorescapturados[index + 1], valorescapturados[index + 2]);

                }'

Comment: a no seria algo asi...  Console.WriteLine("{0} \t {1}", index + 1, valor);

Comment: solo acomoda los valores en donde metes los valores con   \t